# Converting a buffer polygon to polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, buffer, geometry-conversion

I'm trying to complete the following steps. What tools should I use?

1. Convert 2km buffer polygons into polylines
2. Select random point along these lines for each feature using Random Point tool
3. Generate new buffer of radius 4km around these points

Comment: This [tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=13c92d8877054b979ac2f69547bd50f1) may be of interest to you? There may be other similar tools on the ESRI website, try the ArcScripts one too.

Comment: Do you have an advanced license or 3D/Spatial analyst extension? If you have licensing problems would you be interested in an arcpy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To convert polygons to lines, use the [Polygons to Lines Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003t000000).
2. To create random points along the line, use the [Create Random Points Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002r000000).
3. To create new buffers, use the [Buffer Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000).

Comment: Thank you. I want to convert my circular buffer polygon to a polyline and then select 1 random point along the polyline. However, when I run the random point tool it creates multiple random points even though I've selected 1 for the number of points to be created...

Comment: Do you mean multiple points on each polyline, or one point on each of multiple lines? I'm thinking that each buffer polyline is being created as multiple line segments. In this case you are creating one point per line, you just have more than one line per buffer. You may have to dissolve or merge them someway. To check, select somewhere on the polyline and see if it selects the whole buffered area or just a section.